# In python, how do I end the countdown when I have input

Tags: python, multithreading, input, timeout

Description: now, I have done input and countdown, both of which are carried out at the same time, but I want to achieve like this:

1. When I don't input anything during the countdown, it will execute another function after the countdown
2. When I input something before the end of the countdown, the countdown will pause, and then another function will be executed

My code is as follows：

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def waitinput():

    wait_input_str = input("Please enter your account：\n")
    print(wait_input_str)


thd = Thread(target=waitinput)
thd.daemon = True
thd.start()
for i in reversed(range(1, 11)):
    print("\rcountdown:{}second".format(i), end="")
    time.sleep(1)
# ###########################################
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isAlive()` method to check if your thread has terminated.

In your case:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def waitinput():

    wait_input_str = input("Please enter your account：\n")
    print(wait_input_str)


thd = Thread(target=waitinput)
thd.daemon = True
thd.start()
for i in reversed(range(1, 11)):
    if not thd.isAlive():
        # Execute 2
        print("\nCountdown has stopped")
        break
    print("\rcountdown:{}second".format(i), end="")
    time.sleep(1)

if thd.isAlive():
    # Execute 1
    print("\nCountdown has ended")
```